# Install MongoDB on centos without YUM

Tags: mongodb, installation, centos

I am trying to install mongodb on cent os. As mentioned in the question, I need to install it without YUM command. I downloaded the **.rpm** file from [mongodb site](http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/RPMS/). I have used **rpm -ivh mongo-10gen-2.4.8-mongodb_1.x86_64.rpm** command to install the .rpm. It successfully installed the mongodb. You can check the status [here](http://d.pr/i/1feIg/KXHa5ck7). I am not getting how to move forward after this ? The files mongod.conf and mongod also not getting on the system. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What means "move forward"? Mongo daemon is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo-10gen-2.4.8-mongodb_1.x86_64.rpm is only MongoDB client. If you need a server, install a server package (mongo-10gen-server-X.X.X-mongodb_1.x86_64.rpm) or compile from a source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @GabrielBiga, I found that as I was not getting the mongod and mongo.conf file in the installation directory. After some more R&D, I come to know that I need to install the server package as well. After installing the package, its working like a charm.. Appreciate your help.. :-)